# Output singlepart features by default for tools and algorithms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, algorithm, multipart, singlepart

In QGIS, many algorithms and tools return multipart geometries. For further processing, a conversion [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) is necessary. This is a bit cumbersome.

To make just one example: when creating dissolved buffers from singlepart geometries, the output is one feature. Desired result would be a dissolved buffer, but dissolved only for overlapping geometries.

This is just an example, I'm not specifically asking about buffers, but in general: Is there an option in QGIS to run tools by default with a singlepart output?

In the options, I could not find an appropriate setting.

Comment: Would be neat feature request :)

Comment: May be possible using post-execution: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hooks.html Will do some testing on this.

Comment: It's hard enough work to generate the multipart features correctly... I can't imagine being told, as a developer, "But you're not done yet, because the user doesn't want any multipart features, so you need to go back and split them up."

Comment: @Vince so the question should probably rather be: then why the pain to create multipart features at all? Why not use singlepart features as default?

Comment: The one-to-many explosion of attribute records alone is a good reason. The geometry functions do their job with a minimum of fuss, with a multipart as output. Denormalizing the result is inefficient and wasteful of resources.

Comment: OK, that's a good reason. Probably worth posting as an answer why default multipart makes indeed sense.

Comment: The SAGA overlay tools have a split parts checkbox when used in QGIS which I have used.  I haven't used the SAGA dissolve tool which has an option to keep borders, but in trying to find out what that does the help site is down at the moment.  The GDAL dissolve has an option to produce one geometry per collection which avoided the multipart issue when I just ran it.